# Como codificar string en base64 en Delphi

Tags: delphi, base64

Para utilizar el *web service* de AFIP necesito enviar el `CMS` en *Base64* al mismo. Trabajo con Delphi y tengo lo siguiente:

```
unit string64;
 
interface
 
uses
    Winapi.Windows,Winapi.Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
    Dialogs, StdCtrls;
 
const
    B64Table = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
 
function Base64Decode(const S: string): string;
function Base64Encode(const S: String): String;
 
implementation
 
 
function Base64Encode(const S: String): String;
var
    InBuf: array[0..2] of Byte;
    OutBuf: array[0..3] of Char;
    iI, iJ: Integer;
begin
    SetLength(Result, ((Length(S) + 2) div 3) * 4);
    for iI := 1 to ((Length(S) + 2) div 3) do
    begin
        if Length(S) < (iI * 3) then
            Move(S[(iI - 1) * 3 + 1], InBuf, Length(S) - (iI - 1) * 3)
        else
            Move(S[(iI - 1) * 3 + 1], InBuf, 3);
        OutBuf[0] := B64Table[((InBuf[0] and $FC) shr 2) + 1];
        OutBuf[1] := B64Table[(((InBuf[0] and $3) shl 4) or ((InBuf[1] and $F0) shr 4)) + 1];
        OutBuf[2] := B64Table[(((InBuf[1] and $F) shl 2) or ((InBuf[2] and $C0) shr 6)) + 1];
        OutBuf[3] := B64Table[(InBuf[2] and $3F) + 1];
        Move(OutBuf, Result[(iI - 1) * 4 + 1], 4);
    end;
    if Length(S) mod 3 = 1 then
    begin
        Result[Length(Result) - 1] := '=';
        Result[Length(Result)] := '=';
    end
    else if Length(S) mod 3 = 2 then
        Result[Length(Result)] := '=';
end;
 
function Base64Decode(const S: string): string;
var
    OutBuf: array[0..2] of Byte;
    InBuf: array[0..3] of Byte;
    iI, iJ: Integer;
begin
    if Length(S) mod 4 <> 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Base64: Incorrect string format');
    SetLength(Result, ((Length(S) div 4) - 1) * 3);
    for iI := 1 to (Length(S) div 4) - 1 do
    begin
        Move(S[(iI - 1) * 4 + 1], InBuf, 4);
        for iJ := 0 to 3 do
            case InBuf[iJ] of
                43: InBuf[iJ] := 62;
                48..57: Inc(InBuf[iJ], 4);
                65..90: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 65);
                97..122: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 71);
            else
                InBuf[iJ] := 63;
            end;
        OutBuf[0] := (InBuf[0] shl 2) or ((InBuf[1] shr 4) and $3);
        OutBuf[1] := (InBuf[1] shl 4) or ((InBuf[2] shr 2) and $F);
        OutBuf[2] := (InBuf[2] shl 6) or (InBuf[3] and $3F);
        Move(OutBuf, Result[(iI - 1) * 3 + 1], 3);
    end;
    if Length(S) <> 0 then
    begin
        Move(S[Length(S) - 3], InBuf, 4);
        if InBuf[2] = 61 then
        begin
            for iJ := 0 to 1 do
                case InBuf[iJ] of
                    43: InBuf[iJ] := 62;
                    48..57: Inc(InBuf[iJ], 4);
                    65..90: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 65);
                    97..122: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 71);
                else
                    InBuf[iJ] := 63;
                end;
            OutBuf[0] := (InBuf[0] shl 2) or ((InBuf[1] shr 4) and $3);
            Result := Result + Char(OutBuf[0]);
        end
        else if InBuf[3] = 61 then
        begin
            for iJ := 0 to 2 do
                case InBuf[iJ] of
                    43: InBuf[iJ] := 62;
                    48..57: Inc(InBuf[iJ], 4);
                    65..90: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 65);
                    97..122: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 71);
                else
                    InBuf[iJ] := 63;
                end;
            OutBuf[0] := (InBuf[0] shl 2) or ((InBuf[1] shr 4) and $3);
            OutBuf[1] := (InBuf[1] shl 4) or ((InBuf[2] shr 2) and $F);
            Result := Result + Char(OutBuf[0]) + Char(OutBuf[1]);
        end
        else
        begin
            for iJ := 0 to 3 do
                case InBuf[iJ] of
                    43: InBuf[iJ] := 62;
                    48..57: Inc(InBuf[iJ], 4);
                    65..90: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 65);
                    97..122: Dec(InBuf[iJ], 71);
                else
                    InBuf[iJ] := 63;
                end;
            OutBuf[0] := (InBuf[0] shl 2) or ((InBuf[1] shr 4) and $3);
            OutBuf[1] := (InBuf[1] shl 4) or ((InBuf[2] shr 2) and $F);
            OutBuf[2] := (InBuf[2] shl 6) or (InBuf[3] and $3F);
            Result := Result + Char(OutBuf[0]) + Char(OutBuf[1]) + Char(OutBuf[2]);
        end;
    end;
end;
end.
```

Pero me dice : "El CMS no es valido".

Y como verán la función toma y devuelve un string, el tipo string soporta hasta 256 caracteres, y el `CMS` tiene más, obviamente.

¿De qué manera puedo codificar en base 64 un `widestring` por ejemplo?
¿O qué debería hacer en su lugar?

Comment: ¿Trabajas con Delphi 2009 o superior? Cabe aclarar que los `string` en Delphi nunca estuvieron limitados a 256 caracteres. Desde la versión 1 se ha soportado cadenas largas, si no mal recuerdo, en ese tiempo podían tener tanto como la memoria de la PC permitiera (el límite teórico era 2GB, pero en esos tiempos las buenas máquinas normalmente tenían 4, 8, 16 MB). Puede que el límite teórico fuera diferente, lo digo de memoria y fue hace 25 años...

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, puedes utilizar TBase64Encoding.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding

Ejemplo:

```
user System.NetEncoding; // agregar

var
  encoder: TBase64Encoding;
  out: String;

begin
  encoder:=TBase64Encoing.Create();
  out:=encoder.Encode('texto');
  encoder.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Hola! por favor edita la respuesta y añade mas información! Las respuestas que solo incluyen un un enlace, son consideradas de baja calidad, ya que no dan ninguna explicación y si el enlace cambia en el futuro la respuesta no tendrá ninguna validez

Answer (score 0):

Para decodificar un archivo dat, codificado con anterioridad, de 4 líneas, y cargarlo a un memo

```
var
  ArchiTexto  : TextFile;
  posi        :integer;
  archivo, s, nuevo, HostName, Database, User, 
  Password:string;
  decoder: TBase64Encoding;
 
 begin
    archivo :=  'data.dat';
    AssignFile(ArchiTexto,archivo);
    reset(ArchiTexto);
    posi:=0;
    repeat
      readln(ArchiTexto,s);
      nuevo:='';

      decoder :=  TBase64Encoding.Create();
      nuevo   :=  decoder.decode(s);
      decoder.Free;

      if posi=0 then
       HostName:=nuevo;
      if posi=1 then
       Database:=nuevo;
      if posi=2 then
       User := nuevo;
      if posi=3 then
       Password := nuevo;
      posi:=posi+1;
    until eof(ArchiTexto);
    CloseFile(ArchiTexto);

    memo1.Lines.Add(HostName);
    memo1.Lines.Add(Database);
    memo1.Lines.Add(User);
    memo1.Lines.Add(Password);
 end;
```